# Android how many sharedpreferences file(s)?

Tags: android, sqlite, dictionary, sharedpreferences

I notice that when I call sharedpreferences file, I have to supply the name of the string name of the file. Does that mean that I can have multiple shared preferences files?

Secondly, if I wanted to store multiple values (instead of using an sql database with many columns) could I theoretically have multiple sharedpreferences files, where each element is a key, value pair,   and the value from the first file is a key to the second file, and the value returned from the second file is a key to the third file... to return more and more specific information (albiet inefficiently)

Are there any I/O limits to sharedpreferences, such as with SQL databases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your shared preferences are stored inside

```
/data/data/package.name/shared_prefs/prefsname.xml
```

The SharedPreferences class is just an "xml" data parser/writer.

I don't think there are any specific limit but consider using SQLlite which is much faster (even 1000x times more) and provides easier select/sort being transaction friendly at the same time, sharedpres are useful just for storing user options for everything else i would look elsewhere.

BTW i don't know any limit with SQLITE, if you exceed maximum DB side you can always use "ATTACH" clause to use more DB at the same tame (and if you have so much data to reach SQLite limits than XML / SharedPreferences is not for you at all)

Comment: what is the SQLite maximum DB limit?

Comment: Check getMaximumSize() on android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase, please also consider that SD card is FAT32 so probably you will also face a 4GB limit there.