# Java Android SharedPreferences issues

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm making a game of Tetris on android as a project for school and right now im using shared preferences in order to save the current state of the game so that it can be resumed on a later time , i've come to realize that when you store over 100 or so preferences the sharedprefernces object starts working in a strange way , i can save everything but when i try to call the editor to clear (e.clear + e.commit) it wont remove the preferences.

i would appreciate any help regarding this issue

thanks

Comment: can you post your code? are you getting some errors?

Comment: You could read http://stackoverflow.com/q/7420633/1321873 for a good suggestion

Answer (score 1):

`SharedPreferences` are good and lightweight mechanism how to persist data.

But i think for game it's not a win at all. `SharedPreferences` are usually used for persisting non-structured data for example if you have some application that requires login and when User is logged in successfully you can save this state to `SharedPreferences` and in next `Activities` just check it whether User is logged in or not. But in the game you have (i guess for sure) structured data-structures (for instance players and their properties (values) like reached score, loses, wins etc.).

So i suggest you to think about another mechanism for data persisting. Specifically try to think about a possibility to use classic object serializing or and usage of `SQLiteDatabase` which provide more complex solution how to persist structured data.

A main advantage is that you can persist (serialize) whole objects and then simply deserialize them (and not persist them as specific "chunks" in SharedPreferences). Regarding to `SQLite`, it provides almost same solution as classic serializing but objects are represented as tables in database.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove specific values use this:
 `SharedPreferences.Editor.remove()` followed by `commit()`

To remove them all `SharedPreferences.Editor.clear()` followed by a `commit()`

(references here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3687333/1584654).

However If the values remain limitated, for Shared Preferences should not be an issue.